# web3 on react-native : Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value

Tags: react-native, web3js

using `web3@1.0.0-beta.33` and `react-native@0.59.10`, because latest `web3` have install issue on `react-native`, after deep research `1.0.0-beta.33` is suitable on `react-native`

```
const web3 = new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io:443"); 
var count = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount(this.state.selectedWallet.publicaddress);
var contractdata = new web3.eth.Contract(abiArray, SensitiveInfo.tokencontract);
var rawTransaction = {
    "from": this.state.selectedWallet.publicaddress,
    "nonce": count,
    "gasPrice": 4500000000,
    "gas": web3.utils.toHex("519990"),
    "gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex("519990"),
    "to": SensitiveInfo.tokencontract,
    "value": "0x0",
    "data": contractdata.methods.transfer(this.state.recipientaddress,web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether')).encodeABI(),
    "chainId": 0x01
};
var privKey = new Buffer(this.state.selectedWallet.privatekey,'hex');
var tx = new Tx(rawTransaction);
tx.sign(privKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), (err, hash) =>{
  if (!err) //SUCCESS
      console.log(hash);
  else
      console.log(err);
});
```

}

#### Note

1. the same code base use in web are work, but `web3@1.2.1`
2. I can very confirmed the **from** address have enough token and gas
3. have do research said change all hex to number, like `gas` , `gasLimit`, `value` and `chainId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope help other who develop in `react-native`, I highly recommend `web3@1.0.0-beta.34` for `react-native`, it more stable. This problem is solved due to some **private key** issue , but `web3` is giving the error `Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value` , actually not helping if want to deep debug, nothing about `gas, price or value`. Be careful